# Understanding numpy.random.lognormal

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, normal-distribution, natural-logarithm

I'm translating Matlab code (written by someone else) to Python.

In one section of the Matlab code, a variable `X_new` is set to a value drawn from a log-normal distribution as follows:

```
% log normal distribution
X_new = exp(normrnd(log(X_old), sigma));
```

That is, a random value is drawn from a normal distribution centered at `log(X_old)`, and `X_new` is set to `e` raised to this value.

The direct translation of this code to Python is as follows:

```
import numpy as np


X_new = np.exp(np.random.normal(np.log(X_old), sigma))
```

But `numpy` includes a log-normal distribution which can be sampled directly.

My question is, is the line of code that follows equivalent to the lines of code above?

```
X_new = np.random.lognormal(np.log(X_old), sigma)
```

Comment: Do you mean: is a log-normal distribution equivalent to a normal distribution where each element was used in e^x?

Comment: @ChuckLoganLim can you rephrase that?  not sure what you mean by "was used in e^x."

Comment: Err. You have normal distribution, right? You get all the y-values in that graph, use it in the expression e^y, then the resulting value for all y will form your new "distribution".

Comment: @ChuckLoganLim you seem to be paraphrasing the following sentence from my question: "That is, a random value is drawn from a normal distribution centered at log(X_old), and X_new is set to e raised to this value."  so if you're asking, is my question my question, then i guess my answer is yes.

Comment: In a way, yes. But I was generalising so as to rephrase your question in a more abstracted manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I'm going to have to answer my own question here.

From the documentation for [`np.random.lognormal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.lognormal.html), we have

> A variable x has a log-normal distribution if log(x) is normally distributed.

Let's think about `X_new` from the Matlab code as a particular instance of a random variable `x`.  The question is, is `log(x)` normally distributed here?  Well, `log(X_new)` is just `normrnd(log(X_old), sigma)`.  So the answer is yes.

Now let's move to the call to `np.random.lognormal` in the second version of the Python code.  `X_new` is again a particular instance of a random variable we can call `x`.  Is `log(x)` normally distributed here?  Yes, it must be, else `numpy` would not call this function `lognormal`.  The mean of the underlying normal distribution is `log(X_old)` which is the same as the mean of the normal distribution in the Matlab code.

Hence, **all implementations of the log-normal distribution in the question are equivalent** (ignoring any very low-level implementation differences between the languages).